# Vsphere 6.7 disable plugin (NetApp Virtual Storage Console)

Tags: vmware-vsphere, netapp

I have inherited a VMWare installation that has an old version of the NetApp virtual storage console installed (it actually claims to be a "HTML5 technical preview, only for lab environment" when opening the overview).

This plugin doesn't appear to work and we've been told by the NetApp hardware support company that it's likely because of version incompatibilities (I assume VMWare/NetApp has been upgraded over the years and this plugin has at some point stopped working).

However, every now and then I get `NetApp Create Backup` tasks that start up before failing at 69% and sitting there doing nothing until we fully reset everything (As is the case with 90% of VMware tasks, you can't actually cancel it). It also creates a bunch of svmi snapshots that have to be cleared manually. We were told this is probably being initiated by software somewhere, but I'm starting to suspect this plugin as the documentation suggests it has a scheduled backup feature (https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP12412052/html/GUID-3524608B-3A8A-4127-8528-6D99A4E2206F.html).

Looking in VMWare documentation, I should apparently be able to go into `Administration -> Client Plugins` and disable the plugin. However, I don't get any options to do anything on this screen. Just a list (right clicking on any plugin also just brings up my standard browser menu)

The only other option I can find is using the java object browser on the vcenter server, but there are several netapp classes and I can see that ending in a broken vcenter server giving me scary errors about missing classes.

Does anyone have any further insight into how I can get this plugin disabled, or maybe just disable this backup job or confirm what's starting it.

Comment: I'll give you step by step instructions later if you struggle with this (bit busy now sorry) but basically google 'mob extensions removal' for vCenter - it's easy enough to remove but far from obvious. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Chopper3 thanks for the reply. Yeah, I've seen instructions for that. It's just that there's 3 netapp classes (listed in comment below), and I worry that there may be a specific order to remove them to avoid any dependency issues. I'm really not a fan of messing with stuff low level like this as it tends to screw you if it goes wrong and you then need official support. I'm surprised they list it as a genuine option really, and that there's no simple "Disable" or remove plugin option in the UI even though they're supposed to be.

Comment: com.netapp.vsch5, com.netapp.nvpf, com.netapp.nvpf.webclient

Comment: Sorry, back now, if you have no other NetApp plugins then you can remove them in any order you like. You'll almost certainly have to logout and probably restart your browser window to see them go properly by the way.